# Regex to match all last occurence of pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

https://regex101.com/r/tG2wF5/7

Regex : (/[\w]*)

I got a text, 
Text:
"this is a test string with something /in between but this is what is /nomatch1 /nomatch2 inbetween string /nomatch3 anotherstring /lastone /lasttwo /lastthree"

I want to get all last words (i.e excluding words with other strings in between) followed by a /.
so here,
only match /lastone /lasttwo /lastthree

Comment: Please include your regex and test case in the question, just in case regex101 becomes unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select just last three words after `\`; I think you need a regex like this:

```
/((\/\w+)\s*){3}[^\/]*$/g
```

Comment: My regex was written for one paragraph and without `m` modifier ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can match one of your word with `\/\w+`, then only allow an optional space after and repeating the pattern will match series of words. Finally, match the last serie with `$`.

```
(\/\w+ *)+$
```

Comment: There can be more spaces too in between.

Comment: You are adding elements that werent in your original question ...
You had `\n` and put flags on the regex... **How should I guess that ?** https://regex101.com/r/oU1tB5/2

Comment: Sorry about that, but still any hope?

Comment: You don't need the multiline `m` flag.